# $.ajax method is not calling servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am just sending simple parameters through jsp and receiving this parameters through 
javascript in servlet page and trying to call `doGet` method of servlet through `$.ajax()` method but my 
code is not working. I know I am wrong somewhere please correct me. I am using jsp page for input and ajax for sending request and servlet for request handling and I am not using any jar files for this code.

**index.jsp:**

```
<script src="js/register.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title>jQuery, Ajax and Servlet/JSP integration example</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/register.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form>
            Enter Your Name: <input type="text" id="userName" />
                    <input type="submit" id="editCategory" class="add-new-user" name="btnid" value = "Submit" onclick="send();">

        </form>
        <br>
        <br>

        <strong>Ajax Response</strong>:
        <div id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**register.js:**

```
function send() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: 'RegisterServlet',

        data: {
            userName: $('#userName').val()
        },
        success: function (responseText) {
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(responseText);
        }
    );
}
```

**RegisterServlet.java:**

```
public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse   response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String userName = request.getParameter("userName").trim();
        if(userName == null || "".equals(userName)){
            userName = "Guest";
        }

        String greetings = "Hello " + userName;

        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getWriter().write(greetings);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: there is no error and button is not responding.

Comment: the line `<script src="js/register.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` is added twice in index.jsp. remove one of them.

Answer (score 0):

What is not working?

You are calling `onclick` in a input type submit which is a little wrong I think. Use `<button>` instead. And you don't need to put it inside a `<form>` tag. If you want to stay with input type submit then you need to return false in your javascript function.

The thing is that you want to send an AJAX call and not submit a form. So use `<button>` tag  instead.

```
 Enter Your Name: <input type="text" id="userName" />
 <button onclick="send();">
```

and:

```
function send() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: 'RegisterServlet',
        data: {
            userName: $('#userName').val();
        },
        success: function (responseText) {
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: i am using button now but still $ajax method not hitting doGet method of servlet INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Button 1" ONCLICK="send();">

Comment: not `<input type='button'>` but `<button onclick='send();'>`

Comment: does your button click even trigger the javascript function? check that first. Press F12 in your  browser and debug your js.

Comment: no its not trigger my js function.

Comment: ok, do you get an error in the browser saying that it can't find function send?

Comment: no there is no error when i click on button there is no changes page looks as it is.

Comment: so when clicking the button it doesn't even try to run the function.. seems like the onclick event handler isn't registered. which is weird. I have no idea..

Comment: is i need any jar to perform this.

Comment: no this is client side. clicking the button should trigger that event. try just doing `<button onclick="alert('hello')">Submit</button>` and see if it calls alert function.

Comment: alert is working

Comment: open up debugger with F12. The problem must be that the function isn't found. It should give you and error that is shown down there